# Android maps not loading

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-viewpager

I have a weird situation in my application: After building app with release key with generated proper API key, I still have problems with loading maps. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it's not.

Problem appears on map that is on ViewPager. Application has also other MapActivities. It looks like the problem appears when user open map from ViewPager, then change screen to one with MapActivity and come back to ViewPager.

Any ideas why this happened? And how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be because from the [spec](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html):

*Only one MapActivity is supported per process. Multiple MapActivities running simultaneously are likely to interfere in unexpected and undesired ways.*

Comment: You might want to try specifying `android:process=":remote"` on your activities and see if that helps. Doubtful, but...

Comment: Glad that helped: I guess that's how you get around that problem (when I had it I lost days of my life implementing a single Activity with multiple modes).